# Stack example in C++ from Book?

Tags: c++, stack, copy-constructor

This is a example straight from the book:

```
template <class T>
class stack
{
public:
stack();
stack(const stack&);
stack & operator=(const stack&);
~stack();
T& top();
void push(const T&);
void pop();

//few more functions 

}
```

I have following question :

Why the top's return type is not stack& and why the overloaded assignment's argument is not T& ?

Rgds,
Softy

Comment: Please rephrase your question and try to use sentences.

Comment: @VladLazarenko  you mean the thumb rule..i know it is flawed !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why the top's return type is not stack&

Because the purpose of `top` is to return the element at the top of the stack, not the stack itself!

Comment: and the second part is to allow `stack<int> s, t, u; u = t = s;`